# facebook jssdk fb.ui picture not showing in dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I've got this facebook(and yes-the php variable get parsed into a url correctly)

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'stream.publish',
    attachment: {
      name: 'My Social Status',
      caption: 'This Is My Social Status',
      picture: 'http://server.com/<?php echo $finalimagepath; ?>',
      description: 'My social status lets you create a profile pic that tells your real mood. ',
      href: 'http://apps.facebook.com/app'
    },
    action_links: [
      { text: 'My Social Status', href: 'http://apps.facebook.com/app' }
    ]
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);

</script>
```

Comment: WideBlade, did you manage to solve your issue? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Actually-no. I went a different way, leaving the dialog to be displayed with the picture instead of the status. Thanks for the revival!!

Comment: How about leaving some idea of what you did?

Answer (score 0):

you have to configure the **link:** parameter for some reason. Not sure how the two are related, and trying to figure out a way to get the picture to show without a link parameter.